# C Function returning pointer and a dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, c89

I have a function which creates a dynamic array the size of my selected integer. Code:

```
int *create(int n) {
    int *nn;
    nn = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    return nn;
}
```

And I call it like this in my `main()`

```
int *nn
int n = 5; /* size = 5 */
nn = create(n);
```

I think I get the part, `int *create(...)` which is supposed to return the address to the first position of my returned nn. However I wonder, is there a way to not use the pointer in a function and instead modify the `return nn;` part so that I still return the address of the dynamic array `nn`?

I want to remove the `*` in the `*create`

Comment: `return (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int)`) ?

Comment: There are no function pointers in this code...

Comment: `return malloc(n * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Also, the canonical way to do this would just be `int * nn = malloc(n*sizeof(int));`  You don't cast malloc in c.  So the example is a little confusing.

Comment: ...exactly, the function you call is `malloc()`, no stepping-stone is needed.

Comment: is your goal to eliminate the `nn` variable or to not `return`?

Comment: @RyanHaining my goal is eliminating the `*` which is beside the function name 'create'

Comment: @QuestionC Probably his function does more than just allocating ;)

Comment: Why would you want to remove the pointer when you are returning a pointer to memory?

Comment: @Rywi I think you can't. Your function doesn't have a `*`, it is indicating you're returning a pointer to int. You could use a typedef or `#define dArray int*` and your function as `dArray create(int n)` but I don't think it's what you want

Comment: What is your reason for wanting eliminating the `*`?  It's possible but it ain't pretty.

Comment: *Why* do you want to remove the `*` from the `create` function declaration/definition?  What is your justification?  Do you mean that you don't want the function to return a pointer value?  If not, why not?

Comment: @QuestionC - oh goodness - don't go there.  Yes, we can take the safety off the gun and shoot, but that safety is there for a reason.  Let's not play casting / type games to get around pointers.  If OP had a problem where this were needed, he would probably know the tricks himself...

Comment: @Mr.E please no. use a typedef if you really need that `typedef int* dArray;`

Comment: @Rywi all you seem to want is to change the syntax of C to not have `*` mean *pointer*, which you can't do.

Comment: Thanks for all a lot of commotion, a lot of things did become clearer. I am quite new to C, so I wanted a workaround, to replace `int *create...` to something similar to `return *nn` (which of course is not how you do it), however I do see I can just stick to the way things are now or even remove a line or two for efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify your code to set a pointer passed into your function by address, like this:

```
void create(int n, int** res) {
    *res = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
}
```

Here is how you call this function now:

```
int *nn
int n = 5;
create(n, &nn);
```

> I want to use only one parameter and be able to do it with a `return`.

You can return the result of `malloc` directly, since that is all your function does anyway:

```
int *create(int n) {
    return malloc(n*sizeof(int));
}
```

The call can be combined with the declaration as well:

```
int n = 5;
int *nn = create(n);
```

Of course if you do that, you might as well do the idiomatic

```
int *nn = malloc(n*sizeof(*nn));
```

and drop the `create` function altogether.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the ways it's possible to solve it, however I want to use only one parameter and be able to do it with a return. Is it impossible to do so?

Comment: Isn't this over-egging the pudding? See comment above from @QuestionC.

Comment: "...and drop the create function altogether" is the right answer in this case, since `create` isn't doing anything other than calling `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do :

```
int *create(int n) 
{
    return malloc(n*sizeof(int));
}
```

This way you don't need a temporary variable inside your `create()` function. But I don't see the point to make a function that does only a call to `malloc`.

If you want your function to return an array of integer, you need your function to be in the form `int *create()` since an array can be considered a pointer to its first element, that is an integer in your case.

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying one thing, what I want to  do is remove is the `*` in the `*create*